# CasperJS : how to check outgoing http request?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, casperjs

How to check the outgoing http requests with CasperJS ?

I mean not only checking the http status of the answer of a request, but also I what if I want to test that the last POST request was sent on url X and with a body Y. (Regardless if the http request failed or not).

Answer (score 1):

I think you must look at casper event "page.resource.requested"

For exemple :

```
casper.on('page.resource.requested', function(requestData, request) {
    if (requestData.url.indexOf('http://urltotest') === 0) {
        casper.test.pass("Correct url requested");
    } else {
        casper.test.fail("Wrong url");
    }
});
```

It's an exemple, i need a more specific behavior to give you a more accurate answer.

Documentation is available here : http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html